# using SqlBulkCopy to copy results of stored proc which returns multiple datasets

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a stored proc which returns two distinct sets of results (header and detail). I then want to take these result sets, and write them independently into two destination tables. The format of each result set is identical to the appropriate destination table, so SqlBulkCopy seemed like the ideal solution. Code is as follows:

```vb
Try
    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyConnectionString)
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "exec sp_get_order_batch @BatchSize, @NewBatchId"
        connection.Open()

        Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)
            comm.Parameters.Add("@BatchSize", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.Config.BatchSize
            comm.Parameters.Add("@NewBatchId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.Config.GetNewBatchNumber()

            Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
            Dim dtHeader As DataTable = New DataTable
            dtHeader.Load(rs)

            If dtHeader.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                'We've got some data back - yippee.

                'Write the header data out to the holding table
                Using sqlBulkCopyHeader As New SqlBulkCopy(connection)
                    sqlBulkCopyHeader.DestinationTableName = "dbo.web_order_header"
                    Try
                        sqlBulkCopyHeader.WriteToServer(rs)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Me.EventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End Using

                'Grab the line data out as well...
                rs.NextResult()
                Dim dtLines As DataTable = New DataTable
                dtLines.Load(rs)

                'Write the line data out to the holding table
                Using sqlBulkCopyLines As New SqlBulkCopy(connection)
                    sqlBulkCopyLines.DestinationTableName = "dbo.web_order_lines"
                    Try
                        sqlBulkCopyLines.WriteToServer(rs)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Me.EventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End Using

            End If

        End Using
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    Me.EventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message)
End Try
```

However, what is actually happening is the first call to SqlBulkCopy is actually trying to write the seconf result set into the destination table, rather than the first.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without having to resort to iterating the lines from each dataset and writing them in one at a time??

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `dtHeader` and `dtLines` as arguments to `WriteToServer` rather than `rs`?

Comment: Ok, note to self - check the overloads before posting on SO!!! All the examples I found just sent the SqlDataReader object as the parameter, not the DataTable!

Comment: Almost there now. However the above code (when I send a DataTable rather than the SqlDataReader) results in an empty second datatable. I assume this is because the Reader is sequential so doesn't actually know where the second result set starts... tried all kinds of different solutions without success... Any thoughts?

Comment: A data reader knows exactly where each result set starts. When you call `NextResult` it takes you directly to the start of the next result set.  If you're not getting any data after that then I would suggest that your second result set is empty. Maybe you should do some actual testing and debugging rather than just reading code and looking at final results. Maybe you should try using a data adapter to fill a `DataSet` with the same query and see what you get that way.  There's lots you can do to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Do  you have your connection string setup to support multiple active result sets?